# Dynamic programming matrix exercise

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm practicing with dynamic programming and I'm trying to solve this exercise http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collect-maximum-points-in-a-grid-using-two-traversals/ 
But I can't understand how to use dynamic programming.

My reasoning is to use a table `T[n][m]` to store the results and in every cells to find the max value to go (corresponding to a cell).

Using the example shown in the link: how do I know at the first cell `[0][0]` to go to **"3"** instead of **"5"**? Using my reasoning the choice is to go to **"5"** but it's a bad way

Answer (score 0):

You table should **not** be used to look ahead as you are suggesting. That sounds more like a greedy approach which indeed is not correct. Instead use what you have calculated from previous iterations to do the calculation in the current iteration.

**Simplified I would describe the algorithm as:**

- Initialize a table `T[C][C]` and initially set all values to 0. Where `C` is the number of columns.
- `T[c1][c2]` holds the best possible score at the previous row where traveler 1 would be in column `c1` and traveler 2 would be in column `c2`
- Then you can just iterate over the rows:

  - Checking if for row `r` the travelers can be at their respective positions `c1`, `c2`
  - Fill up a new table `tmp`, where `tmp[c1][c2]` is `arr[R][c1] + arr[R][c2] + Max(T[c1-1][c2-1]`, `T[c1][c2-1], ..., T[c1+1][c2+1])`.
  - Replace `T` with `tmp`
- Result: `T[0]+T[C-1]`

*Remark:* I did not take care about the case were both travelers are on the same spot and they are not both getting the points. I am assuming this is handled in the checking because we should be able to prove that in the optimal solution `c1 < c2` for all rows. (except when `C = 1`)

**Why this is correct:**

At row `R` there are only 9 (3x3) combinations possible starting from the previous row. And for each possible position we always take the best. This means we are actually trying every possible combination for both travelers and we can't miss any better solution.

*To wrap up* this algorithm is not giving you the path to the best solution, only the best score. You may be confused by this because you intuïtively are looking for a path.

### Extra

**Is it possible to get the path with this algorithm too?**

**Yes**, but you will need to do some extra work.
Let's say we keep all are calculated `T` arrays for all rows.
Then we can check for instance the following:

- `T[R][c1][c2] == arr[R][c1] + arr[R][c2] + T[R-1][c-1][c-2]`
- This checks if an optimal path is possible if in the previous row both travelers went to the right. In this way we could walk up back to the starting positions.

Comment: Thank you. In fact my greedy approach is always confusing me in dynamic programming's method. So: we have `arr[][]` of dimension 5x4, `T[][]` 4x4 (all cells set to 0) and in the iterations `tmp[][]` 4x4. At the beginning the first travel is in column 0 (`are[0][0]`) and the second one in column 3 (`arr[0][3]`) right? So in `T` and in `tmp` we are in position `[0][3]`. Now what i have to do is to calculate the best result to insert in `T[0][3]` with the max value from all the moves i can do, plus the values `arr[R][c1] + arr[R][c2]` which are `arr[3][0] + arr[3][3]`. Is it correct?

Comment: No, in my approach we are taking the best from the previous row. At the first row there is no previous row so the only value that should be set is `T[0][3] = arr[0][0] + arr[0][3];` When at the 2nd row you should start checking what's the best possible according to the previous row like `tmp[0][3] = max(T[0][3],T[1][3],T[0][2],T[1][2]) + arr[1][0] + arr[1][3];` and so on..